# GNS-Construction: Involution

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.
*(It may or may not contain identity!)*

Consider a positive linear functional:
$$\omega:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad A\geq0\implies \omega(A)\geq0$$

Construct its semi-inner product space:
$$\mathcal{X}_\omega:=\mathcal{A}:\quad\langle X,Y\rangle_\omega:=\omega(Y^*X)$$

Then
$$\|AX\|_\omega^2=\omega(X^*A^*AX)
\leq\|A^*A\|\omega(X^*X)=\|A\|^2\|X\|_\omega^2$$

Regard its null space:
$$\mathcal{N}_\omega:=\{N\in\mathcal{X}_\omega:\|X\|_\omega=0\}$$

By the above it is a left ideal:
$$0\leq\|AN\|_\omega\leq\|A\|\|N\|_\omega=0$$

Quotient out the null space:
$$\mathcal{X}_\omega/\mathcal{N}_\omega:=\{[X]_\omega:X\in\mathcal{X}_\omega\}$$

But why does involution lift:
$$(X+\mathcal{N})^*=X^*+\mathcal{N}^*\nsubseteq X^*+\mathcal{N}$$
Do I maybe miss a crucial argument??

That would give the setting for Tomita's Modular Theory:
[image: Hilbert Algebra]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal is linearly closed. A key step in the GNS construction is that if $x,y\in\mathcal N$, then by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$\tag{1}
\omega((x+y)^*(x+y))=2\text{Re}\,\omega(y^*x)\leq|\omega(y^*x)|\leq\omega(x^*x)^{1/2}\omega(y^*y)^{1/2}=0.
$$

So 
$$
\mathcal N +\mathcal N\subset\mathcal N.
$$
The inclusion for the $*$ does not hold. But we don't need it: what we need if that if $z-x\in\mathcal N$ and $w-y\in\mathcal N$, then 
$$
\omega(w^*z)=\omega(y^*x).
$$
This follows from $(1)$:
$$
\omega(w^*z)=\omega(y^*z)=\omega(y^*x),
$$
since $\omega((w-y)^*x)=0$, and $\omega(y^*(z-x))=0$.

Comment: Yes but why is the ideal two-sided?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't have to be. Please see the edit.

Comment: But doesn't that only give that the scalar product is well-defined: $\langle Z,W\rangle_\omega=\langle X,Y\rangle_\omega$

Comment: Yes. That's what you care about when doing GNS. You are trying to build a Hilbert space, not a C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: Yes but that is clear as $\langle X+N,Z\rangle_\omega=\langle X,Z\rangle_\omega+\langle N,Z\rangle_\omega$ and $0\leq|\langle N,Z\rangle_\omega|\leq\|N\|_\omega\|Z\|_\omega=0$.

Comment: Sure for GNS-construction it is enough to obtain a Hilbert space. But doesn't one want for Tomita Theory even a (pre-)Hilbert **algebra**??

Comment: I don't get it. You are trying to do Tomita Theory without the modular operator?

Comment: I want to obtain the starting setting for Tomita-Theory. That is a scalar-product, in particular it is **definite**. Also I need an involution. But the involution doesn't seem to lift to the quotient space.

Comment: As I know it, the setting for Tomita theory is that you start with a fns weight. In that case, $\mathcal N=0$. If what you want is to "make your state faifthful", the natural way is to compress with a projection (the state's support) and not to take a quotient. In any case, I find it hard to see what you want to achieve if you want to kill a big part of your algebra and *then* do Tomita theory.

Comment: Hmmm... I added a screenshot to the question of Takesaki's Notes to Tomita's Theory. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, the definition has an "if". It doesn't say that it can be done for any state.

Comment: Ahhhaaa you mean like for normal states only? Can you outline the check there, please?

Comment: I think you are reading Takesaki's abstract setting and you are trying to apply it to any C$^*$-algebra. The way it goes is, you start with a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal R$ and a fns weight $\omega$. You let $\mathcal N_\omega=\{x:\ \omega(x^*x)<\infty\}$, and define $\mathfrak A=\mathcal N_\omega\cap\mathcal N_\omega^*$. That's the left Hilbert algebra that Takesaki considers. When $\omega$ is a faithful state, $\mathfrak A=\mathcal R$.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that the involution doesn't lift to the quotient. This is because in the GNS construction we want to obtain a Hilbert space and for that we only need the linear structure of the algebra to lift.